# Rewriting loop unflattening array as reduce

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce

I have the below loop:

```
while (flatArray.length > 0)
  nestedArray.push(nestedArray.splice(0, ROW_SIZE));
```

It meant to convert a flat array into a two-level nested array [a row/column -like setup]. It is working, but I would like to rewrite the above code as a reduce(). I was able to come up with a few versions [doing map/filter], but they were all pretty complicated, doing multiple passes for comparisons. The loop version is simple.

Any ideas how to remap the above to a "functional" version?

Comment: do you have some data and result?

Comment: what has `flatArray` to do with `nestedArray`?

Comment: this code looks like either infinite loop or just NOP, depending on flatarray length

Comment: Did you mean `flatArray.splice()`?

Comment: Does **[this](https://onecompiler.com/nodejs/422gkbwc7)** help?

Comment: There are 93 answers in the duplicate question. A bunch of them use `reduce()`, so take your pick.

Comment: @IgorShmukler cheers all the best

Comment: reduce is a specialized technique. recursion is more general. `const chunks = (arr, size) => arr.length <= size ? [arr] : [arr.slice(0, size)].concat(chunks(arr.slice(size), size))`